# How can I add a paragraph directly after Word table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

If I have a document with a table in it, how do I add a new paragraph directly after the table?
For example:

[image: Example document]

Note the cross reference (which is a hyperlink) back to `Heading 1b`.

The only way I've found to add a new paragraph *after* the table (but *before* `Heading 1b`) is to put the cursor at the start of `Heading 1b`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This adds a new paragraph with style Heading 1, which I can fix by changing it to Normal - but this messes up the hyperlinks later in the document.

For my above example, doing this results in:

[image: Document after adding paragraph after table]

Clicking on the bottom hyperlink puts the cursor here:

[image: Cursor position after clicking on the hyperlink]

... and updating the cross-reference (with <kbd>F9</kbd>) results in:

[image: Document after updating cross-reference]

Comment: Sorry, in my previous answer I had forgot to update fields.
I posted another solution that I checked properly.
If it work better than the others, please accept it so that people can see it first and not last.

Comment: The OP's question is pretty specific, but I think it's worth mentioning that the problem is more general; for instance, one finds the same problem when trying to insert text after a table at the end of a document.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One solution would be to select the table, Cut it, insert all or some of "New text line 1" (or a single Enter), then Paste it back in after "Text".

Comment: This is the only way! THANK YOU! The sheer amount of PAIN and ANGUISH when all I want is a newline after a table... This is terrifying the state of software these days. I can't put a new line after a table without jumping through hoops and solving world peace.

Answer (score 33):

Had the same issue with a document that had a lot of tables immediately before the next heading. Adding text in-between became a headache.
Wanted to avoid copying tables, because pasting them feels like gambling with formats and alignments.

Quickest hack I found was:

1. Add a new last row (simple <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the table)
2. Add a column break before that new row (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the beginning of the new last row you just created).
3. Delete the new row, now isolated from the table

The column break will insert an empty paragraph between the main table and last row. Too bad there's not (IDK) a simple way to delete the isolated last row with a quick key combination.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a simple solution

- Add a new row to the table
- Select the row (by clicking on the left side of the page or drag through the whole row)
- In *Table Tools > Layout* click on *Convert To Text* then OK

Now a normal paragraph will be inserted and the heading won't be affected. You can also choose "Paragraph marks" so that multiple lines of text are inserted

[image: Convert Table To Text]

On MS Word for Mac it's like this

[image: Convert Table To Text on Mac]

[image: Convert Table To Text Mac Menu]

Comment: Good trick!  This also works well, and is a bit cleaner than the original solution.

Comment: Excellent solution, especially since that new row is selected by default if you use the 'insert below' button. This is short only of Microsoft adding a one-stroke solution in an update.

Comment: [Here's a macro for this solution](https://pastebin.com/R7fXRazM). You have to have the cursor at the end of the last row in the table.

Comment: This option isn't available in Outlook 365 for Mac in 2021, for those composing there.

Comment: @Noumenon who said that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/evsgM.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6ntc.jpg

Comment: All right, I'm not sure why my Outlook doesn't have that. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: @Noumenon maybe the width of the window is too narrow. You need to resize it to make it appear

Answer (score 3):

- Generate a paragraph **before** the table.
- Select the **whole** table. Cut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).
- Go to the previous paragraph. Paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
- Now you will have a paragraph after the table. You can write in it.
- Update fields to see that you are done.

Comment: Thanks Rodolfo - this is essentially the same as the accepted answer, except that it leaves two copies of the table in place. But otherwise still a decent solution.

Comment: @Geoff Thanks for the feedback. The accepted question was not clear to me. Now my answer does not leave to copies: just replace Copy by Cut.

Comment: makes sense.  This essentially makes this the same solution as the accepted answer.  I'd be interested in seeing other solutions that don't involve the cut/paste route, which I suspect could have other problems for hyperlinks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Make a new line above the table
2. Select the whole table
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>

This moves the whole table up one row, essentially switching place between the row break and the table. The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> works for moving rows and paragraphs around in the document too.

Comment: This is another good trick, doesn't pollute the clipboard, and doesn't require adding and deleting new rows of the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a paragraph after a Word table, place the cursor in the last row of table, then, do NOT click ENTER but the DOWN ARROW. The cursor will move outside of table, just below the last row. At that point you can do what you want. If it is the end of document, you can write another paragraph. If there is some text or even a header, you can press ENTER and, in case, change the style of text between table and the next block of text.

Comment: This is one of the solutions I already tried, see the note in the original question: "but this messes up the hyperlinks later in the document"

Comment: I logged in just to upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Select the invisible character that is causing a new line (you can also turn on the formatting symbols to see it) and open the *Font Option* Dialog box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) and under *Effects* click on the *Hidden* option. That character will no longer create a new line.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I don't think this addresses the issue at all. Which of the 7 paragraph symbols are you referring to?

Comment: Thought he was having an issue having the line right after the table without a space between them. Had that issue. That's how I found this question. Guess my solution is not what he is getting at but it is a very useful solution for getting a line right below a table.

Comment: Like i said, I might have misunderstood; my issue was that it is hard to create a new line between a table and a heading without messing up the reference hyperlinks back to that heading. Is this what you are addressing? You say "select the invisible character causing a new line" but you don't say which one?  There are quite a few.

Comment: I see. I've had that issue too. I think what I proposed could help that too. If you put a new line in after the table, I think there are two hidden characters. One is like a circle with lines coming out if it and the other is a paragraph symbol. I believe you need to hide both of them. Your new text lines should act like separate entities. Maybe you need another line between your text and heading 1b and hide that new line character as well. There is also options for cross reference links to display just the heading type, number, and/or associated text. That may help as well.